# How can I send dialysis data using HL7 format

Tags: hl7

I have dialysis data.  It contains different fields values of dialysis.

How can I map dialysis values to standard HL7 format?

Comment: Use an Excel spreadsheet. btw, if you want a better answer, give us more information

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use Version 2, I recommend to use either ORU messages for results or MDM messages for medical documents.

Both contain OBX segments. This segment is very flexible and allows different value types, even text.

[what is an ORU message](http://www.hl7standards.com/blog/2006/10/05/what-is-an-oru-message/)
[MDM message](http://www.corepointhealth.com/resource-center/hl7-resources/hl7-mdm-message)

[OBX segment](https://issues.openmrs.org/secure/attachment/34246/OBX07.pdf)

[ORU example with dialysis data](https://www.mirthcorp.com/community/forums/showthread.php?t=6505)   .......   [HLGuidelines.pdf](http://dhh.louisiana.gov/assets/oph/meaningfuluse/LA-ELR_HLGuidelines.pdf)